# Extract specific data from html parsing using python

Tags: python, html, parsing

How to extract only a few select tags' data in Python parsing an HTML file?
I am looking to get the data for just the first two h2 tags.

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print("Encountered a start tag:", tag)

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print("Encountered an end tag :", tag)

    def handle_data(self, data):
        print("Encountered some data  :", data)

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed('<html><head><title>Test</title></head>'
            '<body><h1>Parse me!</h1><h2>firstname</h2><h2>lastname</2><p>next text</p><h2>something else<h2></body></html>')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [beautifulsoup4](https://github.com/wention/BeautifulSoup4) for this purpose

> pip install beautifulsoup4

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><h1>Parse me!</h1><h2>firstname</h2><h2>lastname</h2><p>next text</p><h2>something else<h2></body></html>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tag_list = soup.findAll('h2') # Specify the tag
print(tag_list[0].string) # Fetches tag data on the basis of index
print(tag_list[1].string) # Fetches tag data on the basis of index
```

Output:

```
firstname
lastname
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also a solution here.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
html = '''<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><h1>Parse me!</h1><h2>firstname</h2><h2>lastname</h2><p>next text</p><h2>something else<h2></body></html>'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
h2 = doc.h2
print (h2.text, h2.getNext('h2').text)

h2s = doc.selects('h2>text()')
print (h2s[0], h2s[1])
```

Result:

```
firstname lastname
firstname lastname
```